# Problema con clase Firebase en Android

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Buenas tardes estoy intentando importar Firebase a mi proyecto pero no puedo hacer la instancia de la clase porque no encuentra la referencia, ya intente hacerlo con todos los pasos de la documentación pero no me da solución, espero me puedan ayudar gracias.

[image: Me sale de esta forma:]

[image: Tengo importado el FCM y funciona normal]

[image: Este es el gradle del proyecto]

[image: Tengo todo importado]

Comment: has intentado hacerlo con el asistente de firebase que se encuentra en AS ?

Comment: ¿Qué error da? ¿Ya tienes un proyecto Android creado en Firebase? ¿Descargaste el JSON  y lo pusiste en tu proyecto de Android Studio?

Comment: ve arriba de la palabra Firebase , si te aparece una linea por debajo puedes importarlo a la clase con alt + enter

Answer (score -1):

Agregar la dependencia es suficiente para que puedas importar la clase pero en ocasiones es importante sincronizar el proyecto con los archivos gradle :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de esta forma puedes agregar el import:

```
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
```

Comment: **Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.